# How do you decode the 'data' field in Ethereum Logs with JS

Tags: web3js, javascript

I am currently trying to decode the 'data' field of transaction logs.

Decoding topics with `web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters` works fine, but when I pass a `"type"` or an array, similar to that I pass to yield topics, it throws an error:

`reason: 'invalid arrayify value',`

What do I do to decode the data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, all I needed to do was read the docs [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html).

Essentially, you use the `web3.eth.abi.decodeLog([abi ,][ dataFieldFromLog ,][ topicsFieldFromLog])` which returns data and topics in an accessible array